# If $a^2=a$ find the inverse of $1+a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

> If $a^2=a$ find the inverse of $1+a$.

Note that $a\in R$ where $R$ is a ring and inverse of $1+a$ exists in $R$

I tried $(1-a)(1+a)=1-a^2=1-a$

But I need $1$ in the RHS.How to get it?

Comment: It need not have an inverse. For example, $a=1$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2$. If $a=0$, then the inverse of $1-a$ is $1$ (assuming your ring has unity and 1 \neq 0$).

Comment: @AnuragA,the question says we are in such a ring where inverse of $1+a$ exists

Comment: now you have changed the question from $1-a$ to $1+a$.

Comment: @Join_PhD then please edit the OP and add all assumptions needed and why $(1+a)^{-1}$ is not a good answer.

Comment: When you have *a critical piece of information the changes the entire question* you should put it in the question statement.

Comment: @rschwieb;I edited it

Comment: @AnuragA;it is wrongly placed in titlr

Comment: If $(1+a)$ is invertible with inverse say $b$ then $1=b+ab$. By multiplying both sides by $a$ (from left) and applying $a^2=a$ we get $a=ab+b$. Meaning $a=1$ is the only possible choice.

Comment: @freakish;how $a=ab+b$ implies that??

Comment: @Join_PhD Because $ab+b=1$ from first equation.

Comment: Oh wait, the second equation should be $a=ab+ab$. My mistake. Is the ring commutative? What do we assume about $R$?

Comment: @freakish; no such assumption made4

Comment: @Join_PhD Problem source?

Comment: With $a=0$ we get a trivial solution. Is that good enough? With $a=1$ we need that $1+1$ is invertible, which is the case in e.g. $Z_3$. We can find more solutions if need be, such as $a=4$ in $Z_6$. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @Join_PhD Can you please clarify what the actual wording of the question is?  Does it assume $a+1$ is a unit *for all* idempotents $a$? You really need to be more careful when writing, or else it's going to cause a lot of problems.

Comment: @rschwieb;I wrote the question exactly,I dont know what other things you are asking for?Please ask specifically what u want to know

Comment: @Join_PhD I **did** ask exactly what I wanted to know. What is your answer?

Comment: I asked if you could directly confirm whether or not the property holds for all idempotents or just one.  I also asked for the problem’s source.

Comment: We have cause to doubt the accuracy of how your question is posed given that you omitted the assumption that $a+1$ is invertible entirely at the beginning, and that you haven't revealed its source.  Knowing its source will help us gauge the likelihood there is, in fact, a satisfactory general answer.

Comment: @rschwieb;sorry i dont know the source ,i found this problem in an exam which i gave recently,i gave the entire question,i cant do anything further

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I assume that the $2$ is invertible in the ring, $(1+a)(2-a)=2-a+2a-a^2=2$.

Comment: Please be more precise.  What do you believe is the inverse?

Comment: @BillDubuque Given the assumptions that $1+a$ and $2$ are units, this seems pretty clear cut already... "Precision" doesn't seem to be needed here for this as a hint.  At least, spelling out the obvious would destroy it as a hint, and as far as hints go it's not that bad.

Comment: Where does the question assume that $2$ is a unit?

Comment: I may be that the question source actually assumes that the ring has the property that whenever $a$ is an idempotent, then $1+a$ is invertible. In this case $2$ is invertible.

Comment: @Improve A (hint) answer should not require *guessing* some stronger  
hypothesis in order to make sense of the answer. Too many "hints" on this site lead nowhere. And certainly if one is going to assume some stronger hypothesis then that should be made *explicit* in the answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque A hint must require guessing some stronger hypothesis sometimes in order to make sense the answer. There are a lot of hints here like that which are very useful.

Comment: @TsemoAristide I strongly disagree. If you post an answer (hint or not) that requires additional hypotheses then it is your responsibility to explicitly state those hypotheses.  Please clarify what you think the inverse is, and please state clearly any additional hypotheses you are assuming.

Comment: @BillDubuque, as a teacher in particular an elementary teacher, I allow my students to make mistakes even when they are asking questions, I believe they are learning better.

Comment: @TsemoAristide In my experience students learn *worse* from unclear expositions (e.g. with missing or unclear hypotheses). Btw, speaking of "learning better" it's worth remarking that the above equation can be derived *mechanically* viz. put.$\ x=a\,$ in $\, x^2-x + (2-x)(x+1) = 2,\,$ the Bezout equation for $\,\gcd(x^2-x,x+1)\ $

Comment: @TsemoAristide;why u assumed that 2 is invertible?

Comment: @BillDubuque;you are right,@Tsemo is making unnecessary assumptions